# IAR error with ST link code

Tags: stm32, iar

I'm trying to use the Sensor Tile from ST. I downloaded the project, but when I tried to rebuild it in ST it issues this error:

> Error[Li005]: no definition for "__iar_FSin" [referenced from motion_fx.o(MotionFX200_CM4F_IAR_ot.a)]

Does someone know?

Comment: You might need to expand upon what all these proper nouns and initialisms mean. This looks like a problem linking a library into a target for an embedded system.

Comment: what should I do ? i'm using IAR embedded  workbench the new version because when I used an old version the code worked perfectly

Comment: What is IAR?  What is ST?  Why is this tagged C#?  That is definitely not a C# compiler error.

Comment: Well, if it seems to be a tooling version problem, then you should share the versions of the tools in question. We have to guess that you are using IAR Workbench, which many people won't even be familiar with. The error is saying that a symbol is missing or not exported in a specific object file. Did you build this object file? Is the symbol present in the object file? You need to do a bit more homework. Hint: `__iar_FSin` feels like a name-mangled private entry point of some kind. Usually these sorts of things are target specific.

Comment: This is a tooling problem of some kind. That symbol is an STM library math routine. So it looks like your toolchain is not set up correctly.

Comment: `Tile from ST-LINK` - definitely not from the ST-LINK which is the debugger probe.

Comment: @PeterJ that might be a mistake I made when I edited the question. I'll revert it.

Comment: Check if you link math library - I do not use IAR so I cant say where to set it ip

Answer (score 2):

You need to recompile the MotionFX200_CM4F_IAR_ot.a library with the same version of EWARM as you use for your application.

From the error message it looks like you are trying to link a library built using EWARM 7.XX into an application using EWARM 8.XX. The step from 7.XX to 8.XX breaks binary compatibility on a number points, including the floating point library implementation.